# Function which is inside another function

Tags: r

```
x<-2, y<-4
sum.xy <- function(x){
      function(y){x + y}
}
```

In the above code, I do not figure out why `sum.xy()` just give a non-numerical value, can anybody explain?

Comment: Its a closure: use it like this: `sum.xy(2)(4)`

Comment: Your function sum.xy is actually a function that returns a function which is built with the parameter x and the variable y, not a function that returns a numerical value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the ouput of any function in R is either inside `return` or if there is no `return` (like in your case) then the last "printed object" is returned. In your, the function `sum.xy` returns a function: namely the function `function(y){x+y}`.

You can test this like this:

```
x<-2; y<-4
sum.xy <- function(x){
  function(y){x + y}
}

class(sum.xy)
class(sum.xy(7))
sum.xy(7)
```

So sum.xy(7) is actually a function which for given `y` returns `y + 7`.
If you write `sum.xy(7)(4)` then 7+4 is returned.

I also recommend that you take a look [at this chapter of advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html).